# Django Multiple Choice Field Data Differs in POST Data and Form Data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to validate form data of Multiple Choice field but I get different results on selected data

request.POST.getlist('mchoicefield')

returns all the selected values but

form.data['mchoicefield']

returns only one of the selected values. So I am unable to clean and validate all selection.

Why is there two different results?

Answer (score 0):

```
mchoicefield = form.cleaned_data.get("mchoicefield")
```

It will return data as array.